# Trying to make a matrix solver program in IntelliJ JDK 17 but having some understanding issues in fixing it

Tags: java, matrix, solver

The IntelliJ program I believe is having trouble in recognizing the array "values" for it to complete the matrices (lines 36 and 37).

For context, this is me just doing this for fun. But wanted to try and make a program that could take user inputs using the scanner function (as seen in the scanner array above from lines 17 to 33) and solving it based on a given modifier i.e. (addition (+), subtraction (-), etc.) and printing out the final result to the console.

I will leave a screenshot below of what it looks like so far and the script as of so far, any help is greatly appreciated.

[Matrix program and script as of so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jINSz.png)

As mentioned in summary, I was attempting to make a matrix solver program for the different kinds of approaches based on what values and modifier the user had desired.

Though if there is anything obvious that I am missing, please do let me know as I do want to learn from this mistake. Also yes, I do have a public class statement and the imports done for both arrays and scanner if anyone is confused sorry.

Thank you greatly in advance to anyone who can answer this and hope you have a great rest of your day.

Edit: Added the script that I am currently  using (matched with the image link is details)

```
public static double[][] add(double[][] a1, double[][] a2) {
            for (int r = 0; r < a1.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < a1[r].length; c++) {
                    a1[r][c] = a1[r][c] + a2[r][c];
                }
            }
            return a1;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please select your values");

            String[] values = new String[11];
            values[0] = scan.next();
            values[1] = scan.next();
            values[2] = scan.next();
            values[3] = scan.next();
            values[4] = scan.next();
            values[5] = scan.next();
            values[6] = scan.next();
            values[7] = scan.next();
            values[8] = scan.next();
            values[9] = scan.next();
            values[10] = scan.next();
            values[11] = scan.next();

            //double[][] arr1 = {{8, 43, 10}, {10, 17, 47}};
            double[][] arr1 = {{values[0], values[1], values[2]);}, {values[3], values[4], values[5]};};
            double[][] arr2 = {{values[6], values[7], values[8]);}, {values[9], values[10], values[11]};};
            double[][] sumMatrix = add(arr1, arr2);

            for (double r[] : sumMatrix) {
                for (double c : r)
                    System.out.print(c + ", ");
                System.out.println("Please select a modifier for the equation");
                String[] modifier = new String[0];
                modifier[0] = scan.next();
                System.out.println("" modifier[0] '\n');
            }
        }
    }
```

Sincerely, S.H.

Comment: Please add your code as text and not as an image. Others might want to copy and search in your code and this is not possible in an image.

Comment: Sorry for any interruptions/inconvenience. Just curious if anyone has any ideas or theories on how to fix the problem I am having with the script, any help and/or advice is more then greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.